# Can I create a clone of a clone?

Tags: python

I have done some homework with John Zelle's Textbook "Python Programming". I use a graphics library provided as additional material to the book.

My question: Can I create a clone of a Point, then move that clone, after that create a clone (from that clone) again and move that one?

Or is "cloning of clones" forbidden and I have to create a second clone from the original point?

Thanks for help!

Source code:

```
from graphics import *      # import methods from graphis library
import math                 # import math library

def main():

    # Create GraphWin, display instructions
    win = GraphWin("Five-click house", 400,400)             # Make sure GraphWin is large enough
    win.setCoords(0,0,10,10)                            # The coordinate system should allow negative x and y values

    # Draw the frame of the house
    message = Text(Point(5,0.5), "Click at two point to define house frame")
    message.draw(win)

    P1 = win.getMouse()
    P1.draw(win)
    P2 = win.getMouse()
    frame = Rectangle(P1,P2)
    frame.draw(win)

    # Draw door
    MP = win.getMouse()
    MP.draw(win)
    width_frame = P2.getX() - P1.getX()
    P3 = MP.clone()
    P3.move(-((0.1)*width_frame),0)
    P4 = MP.clone()
    P4.move((0.1)*width_frame,0)
    P5 = P4.clone()
    h = P4.getY() - P1.getY()
    P5.move(0,-h)
    door = Rectangle(P3,P5)
    door.draw(win)

    # Draw Window
    WC = win.getMouse()         # WC: Window Center
    P6 = WC.clone()
    P6.move(-0.05*width_frame,0.05*width_frame)
    P7 = WC.clone()
    P7.move(0.05*width_frame,-0.05*width_frame)
    wind = Rectangle(P6,P7)
    wind.draw(win)
    message.setText("Click to place the roof top")

    # Draw top
    HT = win.getMouse()
    P8 = Point(P1.getX(), P2.getY())
    top = Polygon(HT,P8,P2)
    top.draw(win)
    top.setFill("black")

    # Exit with mouse click
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Comment: Not if you can but could you do it? if not, why? and what happened instead?

Comment: Clones are new objects. If you can clone the first object, you can clone the second one as well, no need to keep cloning the "original" one..

Comment: Why not trying yourself?

Comment: Try and tell us

Comment: @GPhilo thanks for your answer. That was my thaught as well. Unfortunately I get an error message and I cannot post my code because I have not enough reputation points on stack overflow because I am new to this platform...

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no problem doing that, but obviously when you move your cloned point, the original will still be present on its original location.

Comment: Thanks @Dominique for your answer, I am new to programming. I have tried it out, but I get an error message. Unfortunately, I cannot paste an image of the could because I do not have enough reputation points on stack overflow...

Comment: @aurumpurum: no problem, can you copy/paste the error message you have and the source code you're trying to run?

Comment: Thanks @Dominique: That is what I am struggling with...I don't know how. Can I post the code here in the comment section or do I have to edit my original post (question)?

Comment: Hey @Dominique: Thank you. I am sorry, now it works :-) So no need to worry about! In case you still want to know what I meant: My question was related to Point P3 which I cloned to P4, and then cloning P4 to P5. But obviously it works now! Maybe I have cleaned up my source code without knowing it :-)